# Problems with remote graphics (nvidia, swrast)

Tags: centos, nvidia, graphics

I have a command my users are running - it's a bespoke python, using matplotlib.

It's generating errors:

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast No XVisualInfo for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(SingleBuffer), swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::ColorSpace(DefaultColorSpace), profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
Falling back to using screens root_visual.
```

The command I'm using is:

```
 ssh -X remote_server 'LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose /path/to/install/stax_python -- -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.figure(); plt.close(); quit()"'
```

But for simplicity's sake, 'ssh -X remotehost glxinfo' gives the same errors.

Without the verbose GL, you get the second part of the errors, which is why I'm trying to troubleshoot it:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast No XVisualInfo for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(SingleBuffer), swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::ColorSpace(DefaultColorSpace), profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
Falling back to using screens root_visual.
```

This is a new-ish problem, that's - probably - following a recent upgrade to Centos 7.6.

The client is a fairly standard centos desktop, with an Nvidia P400 installed, and the latest drivers.

But I'm at somewhat a loss to troubleshoot - I've tried:

- (re) installing graphics drivers on client and server (nvidia and mesa)
- Using different hosts (multiple manifest the same problem, with slight variances in errors)
- I have tried meddling with my xorg.conf, to try and enable Indirect GLX on my nvidia card. (I'm not 100% sure that's working, but I'm not sure how it'd tell)

What I'd like to do is make the error go away, and ideally make use of the considerably better graphics hardware in my local client.

Can anyone offer me some insight into what might be going on? The X windows rabbit hole appears to go quite a long way down.

Comment: possibly related: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56273 - which indicates that it *could* be due to installing un-packaged nvidia drivers or possibly due to 32-bit app code requiring the 32-bit nvidia drivers.    If this helps to fix your problem, please write it up as an answer.